# Infopath Publish as Content type an Reusable workflow

Tags: workflow, infopath, content-type, reusable

Does anyone have any good links to web tutorials that demostrate how to publish and Infopath Form as a content type and then attach a reuasble workflow to the form?

Comment: Links are great.. but actual answers with content are better! :)

Answer (score -1):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/publish-a-form-template-to-a-server-running-infopath-forms-services-HP010100093.aspx#BM4

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608128.aspx